# Fonts get smaller on Windows 8 - in C++/MFC-program. How avoid this?

Tags: c++, windows-8, fonts, mfc

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I can't find a solution...

I maintain a C++ system - using MFC, complied with VS2010. The system contains two EXE-files.

One of the EXE-files works fine on Windows 8. The font sizes of text in dialogs is the same on Window 8 as on Vista/Windows 7. But when running the other EXE-file on Windows 8, all fonts are much smaller. (That program is dialog-based, using CPropertySheet/CPropertyPage.)

I've read about "DPI awareness", and that this is handled differently in Windows 8. But I can't see how this could cause this - or how to fix it. Both EXE-files work the same way: creating CFont:s with CreateFontIndirect (specifying font name and size), and then using that CFont:s in SetFont-calls.

Any ideas? Why does this work in one program but not in the other? I just want to turn off this behaviour, so that the GUI looks the same on Windows 8. I'd be very grateful for some help! :-)

/Anders from Sweden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a CFont with CreateFontIndirect you should be supplying a DPI scale factor like so:

```
// From CDPI: convert a point size (1/72 of an inch) to raw pixels.
int PointsToPixels(int pt) { return MulDiv(pt, _dpiY, 72); }

LOGFONT lf;
lf.lfHeight = -g_metrics.PointsToPixels(12);
// Fill in the rest of the structure.
HFONT hfont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
```

That code was taken from an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) detailing creating DPI aware desktop applications.

This [TechNet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/11/22/disabling-dpi-scaling-on-windows-8-1-the-enterprise-way.aspx) explains how to disable Windows 8 DPI scaling for a specific application. This may be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks! There was a difference between the applications after all. This calculation wasn't done in one that didn't work.